# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent')

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have written a simple test case which checks the tooltip value on mouse hover in a react component

```
it("displays XYZ Information with 'Code' in a tooltip", async () => {
    (useRouter as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => ({ locale: "en-us" }));
    ....
    const { container } = renderPage(<Comp {...comprops} FLAG={true} />);
    await screen.findByRole("button", { name: /settings/i });
    const creatorCodeTooltip = container.querySelector(".tooltip-element");
    expect(creatorCodeTooltip).toBeInTheDocument();

    userEvent.hover(creatorCodeTooltip);

    waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByText(/TESTCREATORCODE1P8/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

But getting this error

```
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3905
      var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent')
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3905:26)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056:31)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23543:11)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (.../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
    at runWithPriority$1 (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
    at flushPassiveEffects (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23447:14)
    at Object.<anonymous>.flushWork (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:992:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1003:11)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue generally comes with async code in test cases, whenever one is using async code, they have to use await keyword at the function level.

Here I was using async but "await" was missing before "waitfor" which was causing the issue

```
await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.queryByText(/TESTCREATORCODE1P8/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1027**

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same error:

- I had the await in front of the waitFor.
- I had wrapped my userEvents in an act.

The successful change was swapping

```
act(async () => {
  userEvent.click(await screen.findByLabelText('View'));
});
```

to

```
act(() => {
  userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('View'));
});
```

After reading Kent C Dodds [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library) - I removed the act too. Ending with a clean test.

```
  userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('View'));
```